# Ember data: change related model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have model User and related Photo

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    first_name: DS.attr('string'),
    last_name: DS.attr('string'),
    birthday: DS.attr('string'),
    mainPhoto: DS.belongsTo('Photo')
});

App.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
    date_update: DS.attr('string'),
    link: DS.attr('string'),
    filename: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

when i change main_photo field on backend, i need to recreate mainPhoto relation model, how can I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to reload the mainPhoto, when it's changed in the server?

Comment: I want load other object in mainPhoto, since related field main_photo become was charged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method `.reload()` refresh all model data with a related models